# WordPress redirects to not found page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have installed a WordPress on my hosting. Everything works fine, and then crashed! I go to

`mywebsite.com/wp-admin`

and WP redirects me to url (for login)

`mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=mywebsite.com2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

The URL is ok, but the content is 404 error page!!!

I didnt install any plugin or theme. There were not any changes in file system (new files o modified files).

I tried removing .htaccess file, renaming plugins folder, theme folder, but it didnt works. The fields that contains web url in wp_options table are fine.

The WordPress version was 3.9.2. I downloaded version 4.0, upload it via FTP, overwriting every file. I tried to log in, and WP wants to update DB, I did it, and then 404 error again...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check if `wp-admin` folder exist. Second, try to access your dashboard using `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-login.php`. If you get a 404 error go to your home page then try to access dashboard from the top black bar (if this appears). Also, go to your `.htaccess` file and check if it contains ONLY the default wordpress code:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

When try to login to the wordpress wp-admin page it redirected to the page not found message.

The example.com/wp-amdin loading the same url without any issue. The issue is due to the server wide.

The issue has been solved by add the below rule in `.htaccess` rule

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<Files "wp-login.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you set the siteurl to be mywebsite.com/wp-admin;
Try delete the "/wp-admin" part, just use mywebsite.com

If you can't log into admin dashboard, you'll have to go to the database and make changes there; look for table named "wp-options"; there will be two entries "siteurl" and "home"; make sure they are correct.

This worked in my case, hope it helps.